# How to get percentage values based on matrix value when column and row name match

Tags: r

I have a matrix as follows

```
    structure(c(4407, 0, 53, 46, 50, 0, 4407, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 742, 
408, 411, 46, 0, 408, 688, 464, 50, 0, 411, 464, 672, 40, 0, 
447, 359, 382, 72, 0, 439, 342, 356, 35, 0, 350, 321, 344, 45, 
0, 365, 341, 364, 42, 0, 498, 372, 376, 102, 0, 304, 333, 340, 
52, 0, 396, 354, 343, 52, 0, 377, 371, 374, 80, 0, 458, 374, 
385, 54, 0, 509, 367, 365, 52, 0, 416, 322, 352, 47, 0, 505, 
368, 384, 85, 0, 338, 358, 374, 45, 0, 396, 328, 330, 45, 0, 
351, 381, 358, 53, 0, 362, 293, 301, 52, 0, 396, 340, 346, 55, 
0, 385, 343, 340, 52, 0, 493, 406, 406, 49, 0, 516, 384, 416, 
29, 0, 344, 330, 335, 32, 0, 326, 299, 314, 50, 0, 520, 372, 
376, 33, 0, 348, 336, 340, 33, 0, 380, 329, 358, 31, 0, 354, 
337, 349, 33, 0, 320, 301, 336, 33, 0, 341, 316, 347, 52, 0, 
340, 316, 329, 48, 0, 522, 388, 389, 56, 0, 300, 362, 334, 57, 
0, 303, 327, 301, 44, 0, 487, 401, 400, 51, 0, 439, 362, 373, 
38, 0, 361, 336, 353, 38, 0, 328, 315, 337, 52, 0, 561, 403, 
402, 44, 0, 459, 386, 393, 37, 0, 381, 340, 337, 37, 0, 405, 
344, 343, 27, 0, 335, 346, 347, 31, 0, 370, 370, 385, 31, 0, 
369, 340, 348, 54, 0, 326, 305, 335, 39, 0, 368, 343, 357, 38, 
0, 379, 347, 367, 42, 0, 527, 389, 393, 56, 0, 382, 504, 471, 
56, 0, 382, 504, 471, 51, 0, 459, 379, 394, 41, 0, 507, 393, 
381, 68, 0, 475, 396, 398, 30, 0, 386, 362, 371, 34, 0, 378, 
363, 379, 24, 0, 341, 317, 350, 35, 0, 378, 348, 364, 34, 0, 
334, 327, 345, 28, 0, 323, 311, 322, 47, 0, 486, 365, 378, 52, 
0, 479, 395, 414, 40, 0, 391, 327, 350, 49, 0, 363, 344, 370, 
22, 0, 342, 329, 338, 51, 0, 381, 463, 440, 46, 0, 389, 460, 
476, 46, 0, 487, 371, 385, 35, 0, 331, 307, 330, 47, 0, 522, 
388, 405, 39, 0, 359, 352, 365, 42, 0, 369, 342, 356, 27, 0, 
364, 352, 364, 38, 0, 377, 327, 342, 29, 0, 369, 346, 380, 37, 
0, 382, 330, 355, 29, 0, 291, 245, 275, 30, 0, 354, 332, 358, 
31, 0, 338, 310, 326, 37, 0, 347, 325, 356, 46, 0, 505, 385, 
377, 44, 0, 504, 411, 430, 34, 0, 315, 310, 333, 37, 0, 392, 
367, 373, 60, 0, 339, 324, 352, 48, 0, 475, 385, 402, 48, 0, 
376, 342, 314, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 91L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("chr", "leftPos", "OC_AH_026C.res", "OC_AH_026C.1.res", 
    "OC_AH_026C.2.res"), c("chr", "leftPos", "OC_AH_026C.res", 
    "OC_AH_026C.1.res", "OC_AH_026C.2.res", "OC_AH_026T.res", 
    "OC_AH_058T.res", "OC_AH_084C.res", "OC_AH_084T.res", "OC_AH_086C.res", 
    "OC_AH_086C.1.res", "OC_AH_086C.2.res", "OC_AH_086C.3.res", 
    "OC_AH_086T.res", "OC_AH_088C.res", "OC_AH_088T.res", "OC_AH_094C.res", 
    "OC_AH_094C.1.res", "OC_AH_094C.2.res", "OC_AH_094C.3.res", 
    "OC_AH_094C.4.res", "OC_AH_094C.5.res", "OC_AH_094C.6.res", 
    "OC_AH_094C.7.res", "OC_AH_094T.res", "OC_AH_096C.res", "OC_AH_096T.res", 
    "OC_AH_100C.res", "OC_AH_100C.1.res", "OC_AH_100T.res", "OC_AH_127C.res", 
    "OC_AH_127T.res", "OC_AH_133C.res", "OC_AH_133T.res", "OC_ED_008C.res", 
    "OC_ED_008C.1.res", "OC_ED_008C.2.res", "OC_ED_008C.3.res", 
    "OC_ED_008T.res", "OC_ED_016C.res", "OC_ED_016T.res", "OC_ED_031C.res", 
    "OC_ED_031T.res", "OC_ED_036C.res", "OC_ED_036T.res", "OC_GS_001C.res", 
    "OC_GS_001T.res", "OC_QE_062C.res", "OC_QE_062T.res", "OC_RS_010C.res", 
    "OC_RS_010T.res", "OC_RS_027C.res", "OC_RS_027C.1.res", "OC_RS_027C.2.res", 
    "OC_RS_027T.res", "OC_SH_051C.res", "OC_SH_051T.res", "OC_ST_014C.res", 
    "OC_ST_014C.1.res", "OC_ST_014T.res", "OC_ST_016T.res", "OC_ST_020C.res", 
    "OC_ST_020T.res", "OC_ST_024C.res", "OC_ST_024T.res", "OC_ST_033C.res", 
    "OC_ST_033T.res", "OC_ST_034C.res", "OC_ST_034C.1.res", "OC_ST_034C.2.res", 
    "OC_ST_034T.res", "OC_ST_035C.res", "OC_ST_035T.res", "OC_ST_036C.res", 
    "OC_ST_036T.res", "OC_ST_037T.res", "OC_ST_040C.res", "OC_ST_040T.res", 
    "OC_WG_001T.res", "OC_WG_002C.res", "OC_WG_002T.res", "OC_WG_005C.res", 
    "OC_WG_005T.res", "OC_WG_006C.res", "OC_WG_006T.res", "OC_WG_009T.res", 
    "OC_WG_019C.res", "OC_WG_019T.res", "Means.res", "sd.res", 
    "count")))
```

I want to get the value from each column when the rowname and columnname match and use this value as the denominator when calculating column-wise percentage

so far I have this:

```
 NewMatrix <- t(sapply(row.names(res_matrix),
                        function(x) substr(x, 1, 6) == substr(colnames(res_matrix), 1, 6)))
```

which gives me a true or false for matching, but then how do I take the true value and use it to do percentages for the other values in that column?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

long_data = 
  data %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(rowname = rownames(.) ) %>%
  gather(variable, value, OC_AH_026C.res:OC_WG_019T.res)

matches = 
  long_data %>%
  filter(rowname == variable) %>%
  select(rowname, control_value = value)

long_result =
  long_data %>%
  left_join(matches) %>%
  mutate(ratio = value / control_value)

wide_result = 
  long_result %>%
  select(-value, -control_value) %>%
  spread(variable, ratio)
```

Comment: I get the error Error in function_list[[i]](value) : 
  could not find function "add_rownames"

Comment: Do you have the latest version of dplyr?

Comment: The version I have is 0.3.0.2

Comment: See the edit which avoids needing to use the add_rownames function

Comment: Thanks for this but it is far too generic an answer. I don't understand how this is giving percentages or in fact matching.

Comment: Is the issue that the code works and you don't understand it; or that it doesn't work? Because if the first is the case I can explain it to you, and if the second is the case, I hope the code can at least provide a starting point that you can build on yourself

Comment: Perhaps the code does work in a generic way. But how do I match the row name to the column name in the original matrix and then take that value and use it as the denominator to recalculate all the other values in the column? Are you able to help me construct this in terms of the elements I have already submitted?